# Does ungzipping the result of concatenating two gzipped files always equal the result of concatenating the two files in their raw and ungzipped form?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, gzip

In my brief tests, this has been the case, but I'm wondering if the property can be relied upon.

Does `file3` always equal `file4`, no matter the contents of `file1`and `file2`?

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
gzip file1
gzip file2
cat file1.gz file2.gz | gunzip - > file4

# Are file3 and file4 necessarily the same?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the man page, **yes.**  This is documented behavior.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Advanced-usage.html

> Advanced usage
>
> Multiple compressed files can be concatenated. In this case, gunzip
>   will extract all members at once. If one member is damaged, other
>   members might still be recovered after removal of the damaged member.
>   Better compression can be usually obtained if all members are
>   decompressed and then recompressed in a single step.
>
> This is an example of concatenating gzip files:
>
> ```
>  gzip -c file1  > foo.gz
>  gzip -c file2 >> foo.gz Then
>
>  gunzip -c foo is equivalent to
>
>  cat file1 file2
> ```